# Finding the complement of a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have the sets A, B, and C:

$A = \{x\in\mathbb{Z} | 2 < x < 5\}$

$B = \{x\in\mathbb{Z} | 4 ≤ x ≤ 7\}$

$C = \{x\in\mathbb{Z} | 2 ≤x< 6\}$

What is $B ∩ C^c$?

If the complement of C is all numbers ∉ C, then wouldn't $B ∩ C^c$ be equal to all integers, since set $C ⊆ B$, and $C^c$ is all the numbers outside of C?

Comment: No because everything in $B\cap C^c$ must also be in $B$.  So that set cannot be any bigger than $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, $B \cap C^{c} \neq \mathbb{Z}$. Write out the definition of $C^c$ and look for the overlap between that and $B$.

(Also, $C$ isn't a subset of $B$; $2 \in C$, but $2 \not \in B$.)

Answer (score 1):

$B = \{ x \mid 4 \leq x \leq 7\}$ and $C^c = \{x \mid x < 2 \text{ or } x \geq 6\}$, so
$$B \cap C^c = \{x \mid 4 \leq x \leq 7 \text{ and } ( x < 2 \text{ or } x \geq 6)\} = \{6,7\}.$$